# Display a map with the function didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, mapkit

I am actually trying to display a new controller of type UIViewController MKMapViewDelegate
in the function didSelectRowAtIndexPath.
I have a tableview in a controller and when I click on a cell of this tableview i want to display the new controller of type UIViewController MKMapViewDelegate.

My code is the following:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{
// Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
UIViewController *mapviewtest=[[MapStation alloc]initWithNibName:@"MapStation"   bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:mapviewtest animated:YES];

//Station *station = nil;
//station = [self.listStation objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

The problem is when i click on any cell of the tableview the program quit with a breakpoint on the line:

```
UIViewController *mapviewtest=[[MapStation alloc]initWithNibName:@"MapStation"   bundle:nil];
```

I don't know why it does that and how to resolve this mistake. Maybe do you know an other way to do it(without using pushviewController function).

Waiting for your answers guys ;-)

Sincerely

Quentin

Comment: and MapStation is a subclass of UIViewController?

Comment: Yes MapStation is a subview of UIViewController. I am thinking It's maybe coming from my navigationController.I didn't create one(because it is created when the controller is called,isn't it?)

Comment: the navController is not created for your. If you don't have a navController nothing happens when you try to push. No crash. If I had to make a guess I would say you either have a bug in the implementation of `initWithNibName:bundle:` or you have an object in your xib that is connected to a non-existing outlet in your .h file. But I'm not in the mood to guess. Check the console output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need to change the way you set up the application a little.  Follow the design below and you should be fine.  Your major problem sounds like you are not creating a navigation controller which you must do.

Inside the App Delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Create the Window
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

    // Create RootViewController (i.e. Table View)
    RootViewController *rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil];

    // Create the Navigation Controller
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];

    // Make the Navigation Controller the RootViewController
    self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;

    // Display the Window
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Inside the RootViewController:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Create MapStation
    MapStation *mapviewtest = [[MapStation alloc] initWithNibName:@"MapStation" bundle:nil];

    // Push MapStation on to the self.navigationController (i.e you in the RootViewController class right
    // which is a navigation controller so this will work.
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:mapviewtest animated:YES];

    // mapviewtest is retained by the navigationController so release it
    [mapviewtest release];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The problem is that in my appdelegate my root view controller is a tab bar because i want to keep it during all the program execution.So I am confused for managing the tab bar and managing the navigation controller you gave me.

Answer (score -1):

You have .xib missing from Xib name

```
UIViewController *mapviewtest=[[MapStation alloc]initWithNibName:@"MapStation.xib"   bundle:nil];
```

Comment: check your xib file...make sure its file owner is set to class MapStation

Comment: I just checked it too.The file owner is set to class MapStation.It still doesn't work.

Comment: problem has to be in the MapStation class only.. check for connections in the xib..make sure there is no dangling outlets ..

Comment: Yes MapStation is a subview of UIViewController. I am thinking It's  maybe coming from my navigationController.I didn't create one(because it is created when the controller is called,isn't it?)

Comment: [link] http://s1067.photobucket.com/albums/u439/Quentin_Cherifi/?action=view&current=view.png this is the current view just when i click on a cell.

Comment: yes.. you don't have a navigation controller ..that is why it is crashing...to solve this..either do self present modal viewController ... or check out tutorials on UInavigation controller (google them ) .. also you can do ... navigation bar hidden ..to hide the bar ..iin this view..